# How to join many fragmented time series in one regular Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have to work with time series data imported from some CSVs which may look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_a = [["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:00', 25, 60],
         ["Sensor_2", '2019-05-25 10:00', 30, 45],
         ["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:05', 26, None],
         ["Sensor_2", '2019-05-25 10:05', 30, 46],
         ["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:10', 27, 63],
         ["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:20', 28, 62]]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(csv_a, columns=["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Temperature", "Humidity"])
df_a["Timestamp"] = (pd.to_datetime(df_a["Timestamp"]))

csv_b = [["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:05', 1020],
         ["Sensor_2", '2019-05-25 10:05', 956],
         ["Sensor_3", '2019-05-25 10:05', 990],
         ["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:10', 1021],
         ["Sensor_2", '2019-05-25 10:10', 957],
         ["Sensor_3", '2019-05-25 10:10', 992],
         ["Sensor_1", '2019-05-25 10:15', 1019]]

df_b = pd.DataFrame(csv_b, columns=["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Pressure"])
df_b["Timestamp"] = (pd.to_datetime(df_b["Timestamp"]))
```

As you can see, we have 3 sensors. Each sensor has its own time series with measures of temperature, humidity and pressure. However, the data is fragmented in two CSVs and it can have many gaps, etc.

The objetive is to join all the data in one ordered and regular dataframe like this:

```
              Timestamp    Sensor  Temperature  Humidity  Pressure
0   2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_1         25.0      60.0       NaN
1   2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_2         30.0      45.0       NaN
2   2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_3          NaN       NaN       NaN
3   2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_1         26.0       NaN    1020.0
4   2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_2         30.0      46.0     956.0
5   2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_3          NaN       NaN     990.0
6   2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_1         27.0      63.0    1021.0
7   2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_2          NaN       NaN     957.0
8   2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_3          NaN       NaN     992.0
9   2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_1          NaN       NaN    1019.0
10  2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_2          NaN       NaN       NaN
11  2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_3          NaN       NaN       NaN
12  2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_1         28.0      62.0       NaN
13  2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_2          NaN       NaN       NaN
14  2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_3          NaN       NaN       NaN
```

The logic behind this is to realize that, globally speaking, the data in the CSVs starts at 10:00 and ends at 10:20. And that we have 3 possible variables for 3 different sensors. So I want the 2 first columns (Timestamp and Sensor) to be regular, ordered and without gaps. The remaining columns (Temperature, Humidity and Pressure) will be filled when possible with the data from the CSV.

I have tried to perform this using the pandas merge function in many different ways but I can't obtain the result I want. I hope someone more experienced can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First join both `DataFrame`s together by `concat` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and if possible duplicates use sum for unique `MultiIndex` created by timestamps and `Sensor`s.

Then add missing rows with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with minumal and maximal dates by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df_a.set_index(['Timestamp','Sensor']), 
                df_b.set_index(['Timestamp','Sensor'])], sort=True)
        .sum(level=[0,1],min_count=1))

d = df.index.get_level_values(0)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(d.min(), d.max(), freq='5Min'), 
                                  df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()], names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)

             Timestamp    Sensor  Humidity  Pressure  Temperature
0  2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_1      60.0       NaN         25.0
1  2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_2      45.0       NaN         30.0
2  2019-05-25 10:00:00  Sensor_3       NaN       NaN          NaN
3  2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_1       NaN    1020.0         26.0
4  2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_2      46.0     956.0         30.0
5  2019-05-25 10:05:00  Sensor_3       NaN     990.0          NaN
6  2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_1      63.0    1021.0         27.0
7  2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_2       NaN     957.0          NaN
8  2019-05-25 10:10:00  Sensor_3       NaN     992.0          NaN
9  2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_1       NaN    1019.0          NaN
10 2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_2       NaN       NaN          NaN
11 2019-05-25 10:15:00  Sensor_3       NaN       NaN          NaN
12 2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_1      62.0       NaN         28.0
13 2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_2       NaN       NaN          NaN
14 2019-05-25 10:20:00  Sensor_3       NaN       NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Ok, so I see that the key to success is to glue all the data together first and then work with the common fields (Timestamp and Sensor) as indexes to group, sort and format the final output. Very useful approach, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df_a['Timestamp'] = df_a['Timestamp'].astype(str)
df_b['Timestamp']= df_b['Timestamp'].astype(str)
df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='outer', on='Timestamp').sort_values(by=('Timestamp','Sensor'))
df['Timestapm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

The merge function should give you the desired merged output, if your dataframe df_b has `sensor_3`everywhere. The outer join will get everything for you.
This are the merging options:
[image]
 and the sort_values is for the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at an earlier post how to 
[Merge Two CSV files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144272/merge-two-csv-files-in-python).

Maybe it would be good to first merge the two file and then sort them according to your requirement. You can find the tutorial here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `merge` function of `pandas` library. It provides option to join two dataframes on two columns. You can refer to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Try the following code:

```
df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='outer', on=['Timestamp','Sensor'])
```